# unable to install Git plugin in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

i am facing following problem while installing Git plugin in jenkins not sure what needs to be done.

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1317)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1116)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:104)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to install git plugin
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:450)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1313)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Dependency scm-api (0.2) doesn't exist
    at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:488)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:440)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install all the dependencies listed on https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin, including *scm-api*. I would have assumed that Jenkins checks the dependencies before starting the installation, but it's probably misbehaving somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Install [scm-api](http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/scm-api/) and then try with [git plugin](http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/git/). It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just needed to restart the Jenkins, so just go to `http://[whatever]/safeRestart`